# start/affinity does not seem to work

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have been trying to use start/affinity command in my bat file like:

```
    start /affinity 4 my_job.bat
```

Where I would like to run my bat job on cpu number 4. I have 4 core machine.

I noted that when I set affinity to say core 1 or core 2, the job is submitted to exact core as I have mentioned. I can figure this out using the task manager- CPU usage . However, when I submit to  core number 3 or core 4, I do not see the same effect of setting affinity, instead in the CPU usage I see activity on core 1 and 2.

I would like to know why affinity works for cpu 1 and 2 and not for 3 and 4, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

see this page

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/change-the-processor-affinity-setting-in-windows-7-to-gain-a-performance-edge/

under the From a shortcut heading

ta

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Add explanation from the destination which outlines the answer. Otherwise this is likely to be removed.